# RewriteRule is not executing because of similar rule in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am facing some issues while writing RewriteRule in .htaccess.

1. `RewriteRule ^index.html/home/([\(\)A-Z_-]+) search.php?term=$1 [NC,L]`
2. `RewriteRule ^index.html/home/routes-to-from-([\(\)0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([\(\)0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) newsearch.php?term=$1&name=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]`

Whenever I am trying to execute the second rule, It always executes the first rule.
How can I execute the second rule, that why I am using `[NC,L]` at the end for the exact match.

Comment: The first one also matches the second one. Put the second one first if you want it to match first.

Comment: How can I make exact match for both the rules. If I put the second one in first then first one will be ignored. I want to match both the rules. thanks :)

Comment: The second route is *much more specific* than the first. Only *some* URLs should match it. For any URLs that don't, the more generic rule should come second. If that's not so and all your URLs could match both rules equally… well, then, I don't know what you expect.

Comment: Yes, it worked while putting the second the second one in the first because of more specific. Thank you :)

Comment: @AbinasPatra You should put that as an "answer" and _accept it_, to remove it from the unanswered question queue and help inform others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, It worked when I put the second rule in the first, because it was too specific rule.